# Selenium: How to find which element to click in a custom jquery plugin generated select box

Tags: javascript, jquery, selenium

I am trying to automate a click on the **multiple select dropdown** in this example:
http://davidwalsh.name/dw-content/jquery-chosen.php

I am sending the click event to the li element with the class "active-result" (after clicking on the element that says "Select Frameworks...").

The issue is that the li element doesn't have the onclick handler, so the option is not added to the list.  How can I find the element that actually has the onclick handler in order to perform the action?

Comment: Chrome's developer tools tell me the events are attached to `<ul class="chzn-results">`.

Comment: @mblase75 Thanks for looking at that.  I observed that as well.  However if I send the click to that element and set an offset to click the element that I want, it still doesn't do anything.  Does anyone else have any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out by searching the code that the element didn't have an onclick handler, it actually was listening for a mouseup event.  So I modified my test to use:
selenium.mouseup().

Comment: I'm glad someone else had tried this before me.  You saved me a lot of trying all kinds of selenium commands to get it to work.  Thanks!